# Log jam with AppCenter

Tags: package-management

I have installed Loki 0.4 (64bit) and am running it successfully. However I am now experiencing problems downloading apps from the AppCenter. I successfully downloaded several apps, but now it seems as if any new requests for downloads are stuck in a queue. After selecting an app for download I encounter a "Waiting for package manager lock" message. I currently appear to have 5 apps attempting to download. The apps included Darktable, Gallery, gThumb, Image Viewer, and RawTherapee.

Comment: This can probably be resolved with a reboot, or with an attempt to run an installation in the terminal and manually removing the lock if required.